# Convert the background of an image to transparent

Tags: imagemagick

I want to convert the background of a image to transparent. I have used the below script for converting. Also i am converting the image to png.

```
convert  -resample 300x300 -depth 8 "%1"[0] -fuzz 10% -transparent white -flatten -resize 1260x1260 -quality 80 "%2".
```

I also tried below command:

```
convert -resample 300x300 -depth 8 "%1"[0] -background none -flatten -resize 1260x1260 -quality 80 "%2"
```

but using the above script background is not converted to transparent.
Can you please let me know the Imagemagick script for converting the background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your background a solid color, a gradient or else? Can you please post a sample image?

Comment: You don't say what format your image starts off in - though I am guessing it is a PDF. JPEG's don't really have layers or backgrounds so you'll need to be a bit more clear about what the *"background"* is, and provide your image as Andrea suggests.

Comment: the image i am trying to convert is .eps image .and the background is white, now i want to convert that to transparent.

Comment: No, i could not make the background transparent :(

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

You really need to show your image, but if the background his white as you say, this should work:

```
convert start.png -fuzz 40% -transparent white result.png
```

If that doesn't work, I really cannot help till you show the image.

**Original Answer**

You need to be clearer as to what colour the background currently is, and how it can be identified - or show your image.

If we assume this is your starting image:

[image]

then we can make the blue pixels transparent like this:

```
convert start.png -fuzz 10% -transparent blue result.png
```

[image]

If we take this as your start image:

[image]

and set the fuzz to *"within 10% of black"*, we will do this:

```
convert start.png -fuzz 10% -transparent black result.png
```

[image]

whereas if we make pixels within 30% of black become transparent:

```
convert start.png -fuzz 30% -transparent black result.png
```

we will get this:

[image]